# Dissemble a number into integers and add them together using loops with python

Tags: python

I need to create a program that adds together all the intergers in a number together. For enstance if i input 5, the program will look at it as if it were 1+2+3+4+5 and output 15. I need to do this for any number about 0. I also have to complete this using loops with python. Here is what i have so far.

```
print("This program calculates the sum of all integers from 1 to the input value.")
t=0
x=int(input("Please enter an integer: "))
while x>0:

      print(t)
x=int(input("Please enter an integer: "))
```

Comment: Take a look at [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#func-range)

Answer (score 1):

The `range` function in python, when passed a single integer, returns a list of numbers leading up to it, from zero. `sum` returns the sum of all numbers in a list.

So, to print the sum of all numbers from zero to `x`, you would do this:

`print(sum(range(x+1)))`

Answer (score 0):

To find the sum from 1 to n including, you could use `n * (n + 1) // 2` formula e.g.,
`n=5: 5 * (5 + 1) // 2 = 15`:

```
print("This program calculates the sum of all integers "
      "from 1 to the input value.")
while True:
   x = int(input("Please enter an integer: "))
   if x <= 0:
      break
   print(x * (x + 1) // 2) # print sum
```